# What would the job title be for someone who organizes parties?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

I'm currently searching for the right term for someone who

- Organizes or
- Promotes

Parties, "Clubbings", Events or similar.

I understand that there's a difference between someone who *promotes* a party and someone who makes the organization, but maybe there's some common word as the vast majority of those people are one person companies.

Comment: A *promoter* is often responsible for both promotion and organisation, especially for small events.

Comment: @z7sg +1 Then it should be an answer instead (can't find it there)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest an [event organiser](http://www.prospects.ac.uk/event_organiser_job_description.htm).

Comment: haha did I really type "organisater" :D ?

Comment: Where's the difference between "Organiser" and "Organizer" - en_UK en_US?

Comment: z in US
s in UK

Answer (score 4):

Possibly 'party planner' - that would seem to fit.

Comment: In the UK, I think it's usually 'party planners', which is borne out by Google search (9m+). But the same search suggests that 'event planner' might be more common in the US (26m+)

Answer (score 3):

There is a famous movie titled the [The Wedding Planner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209475/) but that term is obviously specific to weddings. In a more general sense, the activity itself is known as *event planning*, and the term you are looking for would be *event planner*.

Here is a [link](http://www.event-planner.com/) with some event planning resources.

Answer (score 3):

*Event planner* is the term that I usually hear although I've also heard *event organizer*. And I used to work with *event planners*.

Comment: True: event planner is a common term too.